# Can a non-Force trained human wield a lightsaber proficiently?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

If someone was incredibly well trained with a regular sword, but had no connection to the Force, would that person be able to wield a lightsaber?

Are there any examples of this or something similar to this in any canon?

I don't know if a Jedi's / Sith's connection to the Force *enables* them to use a lightsaber, or just *increases their abilities* with a lightsaber.

I guess [Grievous](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11/118004/2233059-unidentifiedbattle_dreamsofgrievous.png) is the obvious example of a non-Force user being pretty badass with a lightsaber, but I'm looking for a regular human here.

Comment: In Legends continuity, a great example is Ulic Qel-Droma in *Tales of the Jedi: Redemption*. Although his connection to the Force has been severed, he is proficient enough to instruct (and spar with) Vima Sunrider. He implies earlier that he can use it as a tool, but no more than that, though he's pretty depressed at the time

Comment: @JasonBaker cheers, I'll look into that. And this question is obviously a dupe so I'll close it off.

Comment: @Daft Actually, just leave it open and have it closed as a dupe. This helps people searching for this, but not finding the other two questions.

Comment: @SQB good idea. Will do.

Comment: Human?  I don't think any humans made it long ago to a galaxy far, far away.

Comment: Death watch leader used an unusual lightsaber in the Clone Wars cartooon.
He wasnt a Jedi nor Jedi trained. 
He was proficient with the Lightsaber enough that he mannaged to hold his own against Obi-Wan WHO is considered one of the masters of Lightsaber combat.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pre_Vizsla